# Orbeon : possible to use <xforms:repeat> in <xforms:action>?

Tags: orbeon

In a modal dialog, when the user clicks ok, I have to insert different "template" instances in an existing instance. The number of template instances to insert depends of the number of elements in another nodeset. I've tried to implement this behavior that way :

```
<xforms:trigger>
    <xforms:label>OK</xforms:label>
    <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xforms:repeat nodeset="$currentBranche/../../Eleves/Eleve">
            <xforms:insert context="instance('examen-template')/Notes" nodeset="Note" at="1" position="before" origin="instance('note-template')"/>                                
        </xforms:repeat>
        <xforms:insert context="$currentBranche/Examens" nodeset="Examen" at="1" position="before" origin="instance('examen-template')"/>
        <xxforms:hide dialog="create-examen"/>                            
    </xforms:action>
</xforms:trigger>
```

I got the following error : `Invalid action: {http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms}repeat`

Does it mean that I can't use `xforms:repeat` in a `xforms:action` ? If it's the case, how can I implement the desired behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alain mentions, `xforms:repeat` is a user interface element and can't be used within actions.

Instead use the XForms 2.0 `iterate` attribute in implementations that support it. Builds of Orbeon Forms since [this commit from March 10, 2012](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/0ea9424abf0bd29df90132799161fcfd01173bd6)) support it.  If you are using Orbeon Forms 3.9 or builds before March 10, 2012, use the `xxforms:iterate` extension.

Comment: I'm still using 3.9 so I'll use the `xxforms:iterate` extension for now. BTW, have you already planned a deadline for a stable release of Orbeon Forms 4.0 ?

Comment: We can't promise but we have fixed almost all the bugs we wanted to fix for 4.0. We hope that M20 will be the last milestone build, and then we'll release either a beta or RC build.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `xforms:repeat`, you can use @iterate in XForms 2.0 ([The iterate attribute](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_2.0#The_iterate_attribute)) which is, at least, already implemented in Orbeon as xxforms:iterate : [More powerful XForms actions thanks to iterations](http://blog.orbeon.com/2008/02/more-powerful-xforms-actions-thanks-to_12.html)

-Alain